# Unix tool to show files where the content does not match

Tags: unix, regex

If I want to see a list of files which contain the word 'FOO' I can use

```
fgrep -l 'FOO' *
```

but what if I want to see all of the files which do *not* contain the word FOO?

I can't use

```
fgrep -vl 'FOO' *
```

because that will show me every file (unless there's a file which *only*) contains the word 'FOO'.

(It seems like I knew of a way to do this, but now I can't remember it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fgrep -L 'FOO' *
```

It's in the man page:

```
-L, --files-without-match
    Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which no output would normally have been printed.  The scanning will  stop  on the first match.
```

Comment: I swear I checked the man page about 5 times and kept missing it. (is there a nearsighted "badge" :-? Thanks for the cluestick!

Answer (score 2):

```
find some/dir ... \( -exec grep -q 'FOO' {} \; -o -print \)
```